# Access controller methods from sails service?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have a function declared in a controller but outside of it, so it's a regular method not an action/api.

Let's say it's just does a `console.log()`.
I need to access it from a sails service. 
I've tried using `sails.controllers.user.myFunction()`. UserController being the function but I get `'undefined is not a function'`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I know to do it is like this (depending on where you are getting it your path could change, I put my test in the services folder):

```
var controller = require('../controllers/UserController.js');
controller.myFunction( );
```

I hope this helps!